# Highcharts: Is it possible to have a single series exist in multiple stacks in a grouping

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a stacked, grouped bar graph defined as follows:

each grouping refers to an individual entity;
each stack refers to a subset of data on that entity;
and each stack has 4 bars on it.

The thing is this: each stack is essentially the same across the groups and bars. Even if there are 5 stacks in a grouping, there are still technically only 4 total bars. However, in Highcharts, the name of a series is irrelevant in terms of how it's grouped; if I have fifty series with the name "Bar 1", even if they have different stacks, I will end up with fifty "Bar 1" entries in the legend.

What I want is a single legend/data entry per bar(e.g. "Bar 1", "Bar 2"), as opposed to a single entry per stack per bar (e.g. "Bar 1 - Stack 1", "Bar 1 - Stack 2", "Bar 1 - Stack 3", "Bar 2 - Stack 1", ad nauseum).

Is this possible?

(for the confused: Highcharts is sort of weird when it comes to grouping/stacking. Although a 'bar' would be a set of stacked bars

Comment: Not really clear in your question but are you referring to how to group a series to a particular stack? Could you throw up a jsFiddle?

Comment: Right, sorry. http://jsfiddle.net/6tc6T/1/ -- my goal here would be that every "Locked", "Unlocked", and "Potential" series would have the same legend entry (and thus the same color), as opposed to different legend entries for each bar in each stack.

Comment: Hey what is the status on this question.  Did any of the 3 solutions work below?

Answer (score 3):

This won't really help you get a final result you're looking for, but this is what I had to do.

Set the colors in the chart and repeat them each time.

```
colors: [
                '#3d3d3d' ,
                '#3d3d3d' ,
                '#008000' ,
                '#008000' ,
                '#86B201' ,
                '#86B201' ,
                '#97cb00' ,
                '#97cb00' ,
                '#f79646' ,
                '#f79646' 
    ]
```

As long as you are outputting the chart in a sequence that you want, the output would look the same.

The second step is to disable the legend for half the series (the ones repeating).

e.g. of what a series could look like:

```
{
    name: 'Locked',
    data: [1, 2, 3],
    stack: 'Subitem 1',
    showInLegend: false
}
```

This will result in half the items that are repeats not to show in your legend. However, what this also means is that you won't be able to hide/show the items by clicking on the items in the legend (if you [disable that functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-legenditemclick/) it won't confuse the user).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION 1**

You can combine the data instead of doing the stack and then use the formatter to list the Locked, Unlocked and Potential categories.  This is done by adding the additional data to the data points and then accessing it by `this.point.locked` for example. See [Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tc6T/3/) for an example using your data.

**SOLUTION 2**

Use a [Donut chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut) to display your data.  The inner portion would be the series identifier and the outer ring would be the count for *locked, unlocked and potential.*

**SOLUTION 3**

The [legend](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#legend) is enabled or disabled for a chart not a series.  So, you could disable the legend.  Set each series in the stack to a certain color then use the [click](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#point-events--click) event of a point to get the series id and call a function that can toggle the series on or off [hide()](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series-object).  In the subtitle you put something like **Click on Series to Hide**.  Then you will also have to add another button to reset/unhide any hidden series.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of doing this, but I lose the ability to add distinct click events to each individual bar, and there's no way to visually distinguish the individual components. Since the most important part of this graph is the size of the locked/unlocked/potential parts, this isn't a sufficient solution.